# Unable to build for windows phone with Titanium SDK 5.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When I try to build for Windows Phone the sdk can't complete the build and dies with exit code 1, the only error I can see is part of the sdk for windows phone.

Default alloy app project has the same result of my app! **Is anybody able to build for windows phone with Titanium ?**

My environment:

- Windows 10
- TiSDK 5.1.1
- Visual Studio Community 2015
- NodeJS 0.12.7

Answer (score 1):

Well, not sure we tried with SDK 5.1.1...

But we can build using SDK 5.2.0 - however, there are many things that don't work. The next version (5.3.x) is targeted against Windows Mobile. And by using the [nightly build](http://builds.appcelerator.com/#5_3_X) we could actually make ti.map work :-)

So I suggest you go down that route until 5.3.x is officially released (mid April, if I remember correctly).

***Edited:***

Just for completeness. We are running on:

```
Windows 10 professional
Node.js v. 0.12.7
Visual Studio 2015 Community edition
```

/John